# Using toJSON on numerous results

Tags: sails.js, waterline

In Waterline, when you want to remove something in the model when querying it (say a password), you use `delete password` in it's toJSON method.

If I use a `findMany` Query, using `map` and `toJSON` on the items don't actually filter my data.

How do I filter attributes when I get multiple items in Waterline?

Answer (score 0):

To get multiple items in Sails.js is just like the single item.

Means that you just go ahead and override the toJSON() method inside the model, and then call a function like "find()" inside the controller, and the sails server should call the toJSON() method iteratively.

Just one thing you should keep in mind that the toJSON method must be embeded inside the "attributes" object of the model, otherwise, it should never work. See the codes below:

```js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    username: 'string',
    password: 'string',
    type: 'string',
    firstName: 'string',
    lastName: 'string',
    fullName: function() {
     return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    },
    mobile: 'string',
    avatar: 'string',
    Unit: {model: 'unit'},
    // Override the default toJSON method
    toJSON: function() {
      var obj = this.toObject();
      delete obj.password;
      if (typeof this.fullName === 'function')
            obj.fullName = this.fullName();
      return obj;
    }
  }
};
```

One more thing about toJSON() - it is used both ways (forward and backward during updates), so if you have a calculated field (like: fullName = firstName + lastName), you have to use logic as above, not to get errors or strange things stored into DB.